# Casting void pointer (while working in struct)

Tags: c, casting

Im very new (few weeks) to the whole C programming so please take it easy on me ;-)

**Project details:**
I'm currently working on making a train travelplanner system, using a given trainplan to find the shortest route to a specific destination. This is done making a graph, a binary heap for sorting, and then the dijkstra algortihm. Hence the sorta messy structs (sorry! figured it was the best to get familiar with them).

**My issue:** I built a linkedlist, having data as void inside a struct (making it more general purpose for reuse), however when I want to cast the data while working with structs, I get a syntax error.

The struct:

```
typedef struct  linked_list{
    void *data;
    struct linked_list *next;
    struct linked_list *previous;
} linked_list;
```

And my, probably, glaring error:

```
if(current->((edge*)data)->to->distance > ...
```

This works perfectly fine if I change the data type to being edge in my struct (and not trying this stunt), but casting in this case apparently does not work.

If more details are needed, please let me know.

Comment: Advice: So many levels of indirection are confusing and often are the signal that your code need to be modularized in a different way.

Comment: I figured as much, my issue is i'm using a lot of structs (for both vertices and edges in the graph), who are saved in a linkedlist using a struct. 
So getting to the data gets messy.

Will try to keep in mind it is bad practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
((edge*)current->data)->to->distance
```

Comment: Ah i was not using the extra parentheses correct.. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The right operand of the `->` operator must be the name of a member of a struct (or union); it cannot be a cast expression.

`current` is an expression of type `linked_list` (presumably).

`current->data` is an expression of type `void*`.

To convert that `void*` expression to an `edge*` expression, you need to apply a cast to the expression, not to the member name, so:

`(edge*)current->data` is an expression of type `edge*`